# How do I properly perform a subquery for an ID when adding items to a list using Sharepoint CSOM?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, csom

I'm using Powershell to add items to a list using Sharepoint CSOM. Since some fields are `Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.FieldLookupValue`s, I have to query other lists to get corresponding ID values that are then added to the recently added item. Here's how I'm querying for ID's:

```
function getLookupValueID($_ctx, $_lookupListName, $_colName, $_value)
{
    $lookupList = $_ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($_lookupListName)
    $_ctx.Load($lookupList)
    $query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
    $query.ViewXML = 
        '<View>
            <Query>
                <Where>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name="{0}"/>
                        <Value Type="Text">{1}</Value>
                    </Eq>
                </Where>
            </Query>
        </View>' -f $_colName, $_value
    $col = $lookupList.GetItems($query)
    $_ctx.Load($col)
    $_ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    if($col.Count -gt 0)
    {
        return $col[0].ID
    }
    else
    {
        return $null
    }
}
```

Here's an exploded view of how I'm adding items:

```
$listCreateItem = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListTitle")
$itemCreateInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCreationInformation
$newItem = $listCreateItem.AddItem($itemCreateInfo)
$newItem['Title'] = "An actual title goes here"
$newItem['PjCode'] = "000-C00001CA"
$newItem['GroupCode'] = getLookupValueID $ctx "Group" "GroupCode" "LA"
$newItem['CustomerCode'] = getLookupValueID $ctx "Customer" "CustomerCode" "C00001"
$newItem['TermStart'] = "1/1/2013 8:00"
$newItem['TermEnd'] = "12/31/2015 8:00"
$newItem['ChargeFlag'] = "TRUE"
$newItem['AllDayFlag'] = "FALSE"
$newItem['PjColor'] = "Red"
$newItem.Update()
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

The problem I'm having is that only the value of the second call to `getLookupValueID` gets committed to the database. Here's the results of my running the above query four times: in the **second** and **fourth** lines I moved `$newItem['CustomerCode'] = ...` to just above `$newItem['GroupCode'] = ...`:

[image: Problematic Inserts]

As a matter of fact, if I make the calls to `getLookupValueID()`, then `$newItem['Title']` and `$newItem['PjCode']` show up empty when the new item is added to the list. Compare the above screenshot to this screenshot where I add the item in Sharepoint but comment out those function calls:

[image: An almost correct insert]

What am I doing wrong? I'm really new to Powershell, let alone Sharepoint and CSOM, so I'm sure I'm making some really fundamental mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Client Object Model order in which you call Load and ExecuteQuery methods is important. Every API call like Load or AddItem will be executed during next call to ExecuteQuery. For example you call AddItem at very top of your function and you expect it to be executed during ExecuteQuery method at the bottom but it is not the case. AddItem call will be executed during first getLookupValueID call because it calls ExecuteQuery. Try this:

```
$groupCode = getLookupValueID $ctx "Group" "GroupCode" "LA"
$customerCode =  getLookupValueID $ctx "Customer" "CustomerCode" "C00001"
$listCreateItem = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListTitle")
$itemCreateInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCreationInformation
$newItem = $listCreateItem.AddItem($itemCreateInfo)
$newItem['Title'] = "An actual title goes here"
$newItem['PjCode'] = "000-C00001CA"
$newItem['GroupCode'] = $groupCode
$newItem['CustomerCode'] = $customerCode
$newItem['TermStart'] = "1/1/2013 8:00"
$newItem['TermEnd'] = "12/31/2015 8:00"
$newItem['ChargeFlag'] = "TRUE"
$newItem['AllDayFlag'] = "FALSE"
$newItem['PjColor'] = "Red"
$newItem.Update()
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: Would it be too costly to spawn a second context in which to handle these subqueries? So instead of passing `$ctx` to `getLookupValudID()`, I create a new one inside the function and perform my subqueries using it instead of the context handling the insertion of the list items?

Comment: Well, it depends on how many queries your are going to run. If it is one time job then probably it is not that big of deal.